# Changing the root directory in WAMP

Tags: wampserver

I'm looking to change the root directory to point the directory to the following location:

C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents[documents]\wamp

I know that I have to change the apache http.conf file in the following lines

DocumentRoot "c:/Documents and Settings/User/My Documents/[documents]/"

However, it seems that the square brackets besides [documents] are causing the Forbidden Error to be displayed:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /login/ on this server.

Is there any way to use square brackets in the directory tree? [documents] is named for a particular purpose, and it needs to stay that way. Otherwise, I will need to do alot of recoding.

What are the rules if any when pointing to a directory tree?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `chaser` You can mark my answer as Best Answer so others can also be benificial.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was getting same forbidden error (In windows machine for wamp), after lot of r & d I found that there is need to change default virtual host in `httpd-vhosts.conf` file which is present in:

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\conf\extra
```

(change directory `c:/wamp/www` to what you want)

From :

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost  
DocumentRoot “c:/wamp/www”  
ServerName localhost  
ErrorLog “logs/localhost-error.log”  
CustomLog “logs/localhost-access.log” common
```

To:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot “E:/wamp/www”
ServerName localhost
ErrorLog “logs/localhost-error.log”
CustomLog “logs/localhost-access.log” common
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click your folder, select properties, then go to security tab. Edit proper permission for that folder so that apache user can have permission to access that folder.

I have tested that scenario in my system and DocumentRoot folder with bracket inside the name can work without problem.

Comment: It's not the permission/security of the folder. I changed the name of the folder to just documents without the brackets and I don't get the forbidden error anymore. Can you think of anything else? I'm using WAMP 2.2 if that's any help.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone comes across this as I did.

I had permissions problems on the parent folder of the directory I was trying to set as the DocumentRoot.

I found allowing the SYSTEM user Full Control privileges fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have permission problems (403 denied), and you are using newer WAPMs, e.g.

-wampserver2.5 with

-Apache-2.4.9

-Mysql-5.6.17

-php5.5.12-64b

you may want to check httpd.conf code (ca #240):

```
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
```

and change it to:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
```

Also, you may want to: [take a look at this](http://s2.jeffsbio.co.uk/product_info.php/lamp-terminal/lamp-example/lamp-shell-netbeans-network-openssl/wamp-setup-ssl-virtualhosts-p-246)