# How to run a php file with wamp from outside of the www directory?

Tags: php, web, include, wamp, dropbox

Basically I'm working on a school project with my mate and we use Dropbox for everything but with PHP it's complicated with WAMP and everything. I want to know if it's possible to have a php file in C:\wamp\www\ that would point to the other files on our Dropbox C:\Users\Myname\Dropbox so we can easily work on Dropbox together and when we go in localhost we can access the files in Dropbox and not only those from www. I have tried 'include' but to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

I found out myself after a while for anyone reading this, add an alias in apache to the dropbox folder and then with local host you can access it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472657/changing-the-root-directory-in-wamp <--- Try looking at this and point it to your DropBox Folder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out myself after a while for anyone reading this, add an alias in Apache to the Dropbox folder and then with localhost you can access it.